# Angular: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on DecoratorFactory

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I use webpack and typescript along with angular2 and recently upgraded to angular2-rc1 from angular2 beta. After the upgrade webpack build was successful but I started getting this error on runtime.

Angular2: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on DecoratorFactory - [Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bro0j.png)

Source code here:
[Github link](https://github.com/nithinpeter/mj-admin)

Comment: Where this error occurs in your code?

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot of the console. Please have a look.